# How to fix my code and get reversed order of first and last number in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm writing code that gives reversed order of first and last element in array, without using any function.

I've tried like this example code, but I don't have right output. All I want to do is to change place of first and last key in array, and first to be last, and last to be first, without using any function, just pure logic.

**Example Code**

```
var nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var totalNums = [];

for(var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    console.log(nums[i]);

    totalNums = nums[0];
    nums[0] = nums[i - 1];
    totalNums = nums[0];
}
```

Comment: What is `nums`?

Comment: Nums is the name of array

Answer (score 0):

Get `array[0]` and `array[array.length-1]` and swap them.

```js
var temp = array[0];
array[0] = array[array.length-1];
array[array.length-1] = temp;
```

Comment: How can I get that result with for loop? Is there any way?

Comment: There's absolutely no need to. You'd save the first time, skip the middle items, and then perform the swap when you reach the last item.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right about that. But I'm thinking if there is a way to do that with for loop, how I could do that.. I've tried something but I was never close to solution

Answer (score 0):

If your array has at least two items (*i.e.* `array.length > 1`), you can just swap them.

```js
let array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
if (array.length > 1) {
  let first = array[0];
  let last = array[array.length - 1];
  array[0] = last;
  array[array.length - 1] = first;
}
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

if the values in the `nums` array are only numbers then you can do the permutation without any extra variable :

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

nums[0] = nums[0] + nums[nums.length - 1];
nums[nums.length - 1] = nums[0] - nums[nums.length - 1];
nums[0] = nums[0] - nums[nums.length - 1];

console.log(nums); /** output: [5, 2, 3, 4, 1] **/
```

If the values may contain non-numeric ones then a temporary variable is used :

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

let aux = nums[0];

nums[0] = nums[nums.length - 1];
nums[nums.length - 1] = aux;

console.log(nums); /** output: [5, 2, 3, 4, 1] **/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
const temp = nums[0]
nums[0] = nums[nums.length-1]
nums[nums.length-1] = temp
```

Result: `[9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1]`

Answer (score 0):

You could swap the elements using this short snippet:

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 3];

// swap first and last elements
[nums[0], nums[nums.length - 1]] = [nums[nums.length - 1], nums[0]];

console.log(nums);
```